# Jump to next unread in different folder

Tags: thunderbird

I know I can press `N` to skip to next unread message, but if the next unread message is in another folder, Thunderbird will show Yes/No confirmation dialog.  That means I actually have to press `N` and `Y`, even if I did pay attention to unread count so I'm aware what I'm doing so the popup does not bring any value and just feels like a chore.

I looked into official shortcut list and have not found anything.  Is there a (hidden) setting that would just remove the confirmation and let me always just skip to next unread no matter where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set mailnews.nav_crosses_folders to 0 to remove popup confirmation.

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=667165

To access the config editor, go to Edit > Preferences, select the Advanced panel, select the General tab, and click Config Editor….

The first time you do this, you will get a warning telling you to be careful.

Type "mailnews.nav_crosses_folders" in the search field and set value to 0.